# Override declared encoding during unmarshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, encoding, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an XML file with its encoding set within it: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>` but really file is encoded in UTF-8. Is there a way to override encoding declared in XML file when unmarshalling it with JAXB?

Comment: I know this is kind of late, but I don't think that's technically legal. And it's DEFINITELY not a good idea.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can unmarshal the content from a `java.io.Reader` in order to supply the actual encoding:

```
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("input.xml");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
try {
    Address address = (Address) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
} finally  {
    reader.close();
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html