# error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251 in UTF-8 file when I try generate JAXB classes

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jaxb

I have `XSD` with word - `'Идентификатор'`. When I generate JAXB class from this XSD I have this output in log:

```
error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
 *                     Р?РґРµРЅС‚РёС„РёРєР°С‚РѕСЂ
```

When I decode this string I get this:

`�?дентификатор` I try change `'И'` symbol but it not helped. I write this symbol in `Notpade++` with `UTF-8 encoding` and cut and past to my `XSD` and it not helped. My `XSD` has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and file

[image]

I don't know what else to do to fix it.

Comment: you have to set the encoding for your marshaller...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332329/override-declared-encoding-during-unmarshalling-with-jaxb